In virt-manager, what is the difference between a VirtIO, Red Hat or QEMU SCSI disk?
After my previous experience of migrating IDE VM disks to VirtIO SCSI, I created a Win10 VM in virt-manager, with the primary disk being a SCSI disk from setup.
In virt-manager, I created a VirtIO SCSI controller:
<controller type="scsi" index="0" model="virtio-scsi">
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</controller>

I then created a disk (SCSI Disk 1) that, according to virt-manager, is using the SCSI bus type:
<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2" discard="unmap"/>
  <source file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/win10-enterprise.qcow2"/>
  <target dev="sda" bus="scsi"/>
  <boot order="2"/>
  <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="0"/>
</disk>


During the Win10 setup, I mounted the RedHat VirtIO ISO and installed the drivers so that Win10 could be installed to the SCSI disk:

After installation, I added another disk (VirtIO Disk 1) to the VM.  This time in virt-manager, I chose VirtIO as the bus type:
<disk type="file" device="disk">
  <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2" discard="unmap"/>
  <source file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/win10-enterprise-1.qcow2"/>
  <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x06" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</disk>

The VirtIO disk does not appear to be linked to any of the listed controllers on the VM overview in virt-manager.  I assumed this disk to be a VirtIO Block device.
In the Win10 guest VM, I noticed in the Device Manager that the primary SCSI disk is labelled as a "QEMU SCSI" disk, and the VirtIO disk as a "RedHat VirtIO SCSI" disk.
The VirtIO storage controller used for the SCSI disk is labelled as a "Red Hat VirtIO SCSI controller":

I am confused why the SCSI disk is not labelled as a VirtIO SCSI disk, and how the VirtIO disk (assumed to be VirtIO Block) is a "VirtIO SCSI" disk without being attached to any kind of SCSI controller.
Q: Is there any difference between the disks I have configured for this VM?
Q: From virt-manager's perspective, what is the difference between disks that use the VirtIO and SCSI bus types, and how they are represented within a VM?
Q: Are there any performance differences between disks using the different bus types?

"VirtIO" is a general framework of virtual PCI devices that are meant to offer higher performance than traditional emulated devices (as well as being simpler – physical hardware often has many frills that a virtual device doesn't need).
There are two different VirtIO storage devices:

Plain 'VirtIO block access' device that is completely custom, with little or no relationship with common physical storage devices. This shows up as /dev/vd* on Linux, uses the viostor driver on Windows, and is limited to one disk per PCI slot.

Full 'VirtIO SCSI controller' device that behaves like a typical SCSI disk controller with the same concepts (SCSI commands, targets, LUNs). This shows up as /dev/sd* on Linux (vioscsi on Windows) and can expose multiple disks through a single controller.


While both require custom drivers on Windows (there's no standard driver for SCSI controllers like there is one for SATA AHCI), in the latter case the 'vioscsi' guest drivers can simply pass through the SCSI commands to the hypervisor [and the hypervisor might, in theory, pass them through to a physical SAS disk], whereas in the case of "VirtIO block" the guest drivers have to pretend to be an SCSI disk so that Windows would know how to deal with it – a lot of the SCSI command handling is done (emulated) inside the 'viostor' driver.

I am confused why the SCSI disk is not labelled as a VirtIO SCSI disk, and how the VirtIO disk (assumed to be VirtIO Block) is a "VirtIO SCSI" disk without being attached to any kind of SCSI controller.

The Windows driver pretends to be SCSI, because the OS already knows how to talk to an SCSI disk, so although it means the "viostor" driver needs to emulate SCSI command handling, it also means the driver doesn't need to handle various other specifics – it can let the existing OS SCSI support deal with that.

Q: From virt-manager's perspective, what is the difference between disks that use the VirtIO and SCSI bus types, and how they are represented within a VM?

Both are connected as PCI devices, but:

"VirtIO block" disks are always one per PCI slot, with the PCI device itself being a custom type of storage device. Windows "viostor" drivers pretend that it is an SCSI disk (handling the SCSI commands within the driver), while Linux drivers expose it as a custom /dev/vd* device.

"VirtIO SCSI" disks can share one controller, with disks being SCSI devices accessible through that controller. Both the Windows "vioscsi" drivers and the Linux drivers only need to initialize the SCSI controller, but relay the actual commands between guest and hypervisor (or guest and physical disk), hence the label 'SCSI pass-through'.



Q: Are there any performance differences between disks using the different bus types?

There shouldn't be any significant performance differences; I've heard that in theory "VirtIO block" might perform better, but in situations where I didn't need to squeeze out the last bits of performance, I'd prefer "VirtIO SCSI" due to its cleaner integration.

You are right in regards to the disk descriptor for both virtio-blk and scsi disks. virsh reports the VirtIO disk to be vda, therefore a virtio-blk device.  It was not possible to determine within the Windows guest OS whether the driver being used for a disk was either viostor or vioscsi.  The driver details do not reveal this, but the Device Stack property in the Details tab for each disk within Windows Device Manager does. It states whether \Driver\viostor or \Driver\vioscsi is being used.
